# How would I overwrite the fav_genre of the user in this code

Tags: python

So I'm developing a code for a very basic music app, Every users information is saved into the database using the following format:

```
usrFile_write.write(username + ' : ' + password + ' : ' + name + ' : ' + dob + ' : ' + fav_artist + ' : ' + fav_genre + ' : ' + '\n' )
```

now I want to read the existing information of a particular user and allow them to change their fav_genre. Below is my failed attempt to do so:

```
textfile = 'user_DB.txt'
def a():
    username = input('name?: ')
    with open(textfile, 'r+') as textIn:
        for line in textIn:
            information = line.split(" : ")
            if information[0] == username:
                print('Your current genre is:',information[5])
                new_genre = input('what would you like your new genre to be?')
                information[5] = new_genre
                textIn.write(information[5]=new_genre)#this line
                print('new genre is saved to',information[5])
                break
            elif information != username:
                print('Name not found, Please try again')
                a()
            else:print('invalid')
            break
    textIn.close()

a()
```

The line with the comment #this line is where I think the error is occouring as I want to overwrite the previous value of fav_genre for that specific user with the new one.Any ideas on what I could do different to make this work?

Comment: Updated answer - Please check it out

Answer (score -1):

Basically change that line to:

```
textfile.write(' : '.join(information.values()) + '\n' )
```

So full code:

```
textfile = 'user_DB.txt'
updated_textfile = 'user_DB_Updated.txt'
def a():
    username = input('name?: ')
    updated_lines = []
    with open(textfile, 'r+') as textIn:
        for line in textIn:
            information = line.split(" : ")
            updated_lines.append(line)
            if information[0] == username:
                print('Your current genre is:',information[5])
                new_genre = input('what would you like your new genre to be?')
                information[5] = new_genre
                updated_lines[-1] = ' : '.join(information) + '\n' 
                print('new genre is saved to ',information[5])
                break
            elif information != username:
                print('Name not found, Please try again')
                a()
            else:print('invalid')
            break
    with open(updated_textfile, 'w+') as out_text:
        out_text.write(''.join(updated_lines))
    textfile.close()

a()
```

Comment: this code doesn't update the existing information in the database but it just duplicates it and changes the genre: so if my old set of values was:'dj : amul : Devjyot : 11/07/2001 : ed sheeran : pop : ' it creates another line with the same info but different genre:'dj : amul : Devjyot : 11/07/2001 : ed sheeran : jazz : ' and it leaves me with 2 lines in the database rather than just one updated line

Comment: Updated my answer so that each line gets sent to an updated_lines list, we replace the last entry in the list (i.e. current line) if we change the genre. At the end we join every line and write it back out to the file

Comment: @user8954037 - Please notice you have to set variable: updated_textfile

Comment: I used 'user_DB_Updated.txt' so you dont overwrite the original file in case something is wrong.

Comment: everything seems to be fine, so how would I change the code so it inputs to the orginal file? and please note that you need to close 'textIn' and not 'textfile'

Comment: Change  with open(updated_textfile, 'w+') as out_text: to  with open(textfile, 'w+') as out_text:

Comment: If it worked please consider removing the downvote and marking the answer as correct. Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: I didn't cast the downvote but it anycase the answer works perfectly thanks

Comment: Please mark it as correct then so its closed. Thanks